# jsp:element creates <img></img> element

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

In trying to clean up some pretty crufty code I rewrote something this way:

```
<jsp:element name="img">
    <jsp:attribute name="src">
        <c:url value="${akamai}/images/prdLargerImage.gif"/>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="alt">Zoom Image</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

…but was surprised to discover that JSP generated this code:

```
<img src="/images/prdLargerImage.gif" alt="Zoom Image">


            </img>
```

Is there any way to force it to generate `<img src="/images/prdLargerImage.gif" alt="Zoom Image"/>`?

Comment: I should point out I also tried the above code with all anonymous whitespace removed manually. The result was `<img src="/images/prdLargerImage.gif" alt="Zoom Image"></img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the container to trim that whitespace away by the following entry in `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

There's nothing you can do against having a dangling `</img>` instead of a short tag `<img/>`.

However, if you target a Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 compatible container (where EL in template text is supported), I'd rather just rewrite that piece of ugliness (which offers imo totally no extra advantages) like follows:

```
<img src="${akamai}/images/prdLargerImage.gif" alt="Zoom Image" />
```

Comment: That's certainly a clean solution (if only I were on JSP 2.0) in all cases where I can trust `akamai` to contain an XML/URL safe value. In the meantime it looks like I'll have to write malformed-XML JSP or have open/close `img` tags.

Comment: The `<c:url>` does not XML/URL-encode its `value`. It only URL-encodes the `value` of any nested `<c:param>`.